# How can I iterate over the keys and values of a String Template 4 Map?

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

In StringTemplate 4, the default behavior for iteration is to iterate over the `keys` instead of the `values`, which was the behavior in version 3.

I can not find the syntax for how to iterate over the `keys` **and** `values` at the same time for version 4.

**Can someone post an example of the syntax?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use indirect property referencing to get the value for the key in the current iteration. Is this what you mean?

```
<myMap.keys:{k | <k> maps to <myMap.(k)>}; separator="\n">
```

prints:

```
Jake maps to Dog
Finn maps to Human
```

Comment: bonus rep for the Adventure Time reference!

Answer (score 0):

Sample input :

```
List<String> myList  =  new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("k1");
myList.add("k2");
myList.add("k3");


Map<String,String> myMap =  new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("k1", "v1");
myMap.put("k2", "v2");
myMap.put("k3", "v3");
```

- Prints key-value pairs in random order.

  ```
     $myMap.keys:{key | $key$  maps to $myMap.(key)$ }; separator="\n"$
  ```

Output:(random order)

```
 k3 maps to v3
 k1 maps to v1
 k2 maps to v2
```

- Prints key-value pairs in-order defined by list.

  ```
    $myList:{item | $item$  maps to $myMap.(item)$ }; separator="\n"$
  ```

Output:(ordered)

```
 k1 maps to v1
 k2 maps to v2
 k3 maps to v3
```